# Get LogCat From Android Device Manually

Tags: android, logging, logcat

My phone cannot connect to the android ADB but I need to check its logs since it seems to be getting unique errors from an app I made. aLogcat app is outdated and getting "bug reports" from developer options is unreadable for me.

Is there any way for me to get a logcat report of my app while I'm running an application on it?

Edit: I use a droid Mini phone and it won't connect to eclipse. After installing the specific driver for the device it worked.

Comment: "My phone cannot connect to the android ADB" -- why? What is the specific problem? "Is there any way for me to get a logcat report of my app while I'm running an application on it?" -- not on Android 4.1+: http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/12/read-logs-regression.html

Comment: @CommonsWare Applications can still collect their own logcat reports which is what the author needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, consider making ADB work for your device. Provided this is totally impossible, consider using [ACRA](http://acra.ch/). If you don't want to integrate fully with it, check [their logcat collection code](https://code.google.com/p/acra/source/browse/trunk/acra/src/main/java/org/acra/collector/LogCatCollector.java).